# How to solve Jhipster Error of Metadata version mismatch for module primeng domhandler.d.ts

Tags: angular, jhipster, primeng

I am using jhipster generator version 4.11.1

Upon compiling JHipster project for production with 
`/mvnw package -Pprod`, I got the following error:

> jhipster Error: Metadata version mismatch for module
>   /Users/guntar/Codes/genpro4des/node_modules/primeng/components/dom/domhandler.d.ts,
>   found version 4, expected 3

So how should this problem be handled?

Answer (score 1):

This is because I installed primeng with generic command of:

```
yarn add primeng
yarn add @angular/animations
```

which will automatically install primeng version 5 released on November 20th. Meanwhile, primeng 5 does not work with Angular 4 of current jHipster.

From [PrimeNG Blog](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-5-0-0-released/)

> PrimeNG 5 fully support Angular 5, if your project is on Angular 4,
>   the PrimeNG version to use would be 4.x as PrimeNG 5 does not work on
>   Angular 4 due to AOT constraints.

So, the thing I do was uninstal my existing primeng installation, and install the compatible version. Don't bother reinstalling CLI.

```
yarn remove primeng
```

It also means that if you want to integrate prime-ng on your jHipster project, **you should state the primeng version explicitly** for both the primeng and angular animation.

```
yarn add primeng@4.2.1

yarn add @angular/animations@4.4.6
```

I was also getting error of MessageModule on my import declaration which is not supported by PrimeNG 4, so I had it removed.

Off course, the other alternative is to upgrade your JHipster to release 4.12.0 - if you can afford to lose all the customization you've made, that is :-)

Comment: `jhipster upgrade` does a pretty good job keeping your customizations using git merge. Have you tried it?

Comment: No I haven't tried it yet. Thanks for the tip! The last time I tried jhipster upgrade, I didn't see any git merge option (and lost all of my customizations). I guess I haven't properly learn about how to upgrade existing jHipster project.

Comment: There's a nice doc with a graphical representation http://www.jhipster.tech/upgrading-an-application/

Comment: and how did I miss that?! Thanks, Man!